# linux bluetooth firmware missing

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, firmware

The kernel is trying to load a bluetooth firmware version that does not exists.

dmesg:

```
[    4.435796] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011001140d00
[    4.436742] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.1.14.d.bseq failed with error -2
[    4.436748] Bluetooth: hci0 failed to open Intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.1.14.d.bseq(-2)
```

In /lib/firmware/intel, I have:

ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq

ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq

If I create a symlink to any of these two, it fails to load with error code -16. ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.1.14.d.bseq is nowhere to be found.
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Check your distribution's documentation.

Comment: Take a look what I did on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305111/cant-connect-to-bluetooth-devices-i-e-speakers-on-debian-jessie/305112#305112).